# Arquivo CMD e Agendador de Tarefas

Tags: cmd, scheduler

Uso o sistema `Windows Server 2008`, e preciso executar um `cmd` pelo `agendador de tarefas`, porém quando faço a tarefa, ele só executa o `cmd` mas não executa seu conteúdo, alguém saberia como resolver?

Comment: Coloque aqui os comandos que você quer que execute.

Comment: Compartilhe o comando que tentou executar.

Comment: java -cp "Edi7WebCli.jar" webclicfg.Edi7WebCli.Main -cATIVASE -p025 -tP

Comment: Não seria questão de privilégio? O CMD teria que ser iniciado como administrador?